# what is a reasonable solution to get gaps in-between specific elements?

Tags: html, css

what is a reasonable solution to get a gap in-between these elements?

What my goal is to get a gap in between `<h2>Subtitle</h2>`, `<h3>STARS, Tartopp Road</h3>` along with the paragraph element.

I have already tried utilizing line break however it becomes too large leading me to use line-height or margin-bottom within `<br/>`.

...just to mention 'margin-bottom: -10px;' was used decrease the gapes between lines

I AM EXTREMELY SORRY STRUGGLING TO GET MY CODE ONTO BODY THEREFORE IM USING JSFIDDLE. LINK BELOW.

Im trying to get this layout[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNcv9.png)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kztfej4m/3/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

```css
grid-gap: 1em;
```

grid-gap is your friend here. You're using the `display:grid` system which allows you to specify the gap between elements consistently. After this gap you can format individual elements such as your `p, h1, h2` selectors with more specific margin/padding/line-height to fit your needs.

Update: The image you provided shows your trying to achieve a different spacing which you could easily do without blanking out all the default margins and padding for the h1, h2, h3 and p elements in your CSS.

[Here is a j-Fiddle with some adjustments and taking out the grid display system](https://jsfiddle.net/cnrom41w/4/). Obviously it's a quick draft which needs small adjustments but let the semantics of your HTML control your structure:

```html
   <div class="grid-item-workshops">
      <!-- 
        Use header to group your headers together
        so they can be easily formatted in your CSS
      -->
      <header>
        <h1>WORKSHOP TITLE</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
      </header> 

      <!--
         Use a br in the midst of the h3 if you 
         want to keep these grouped as a sub-header with the date.
         Or even better, use the <date> and <address> tags here 
         so you can format them separately. This has the nice 
         side effect smaller margins as they're not h3 tags.
      -->
      <date>25-29th July 2016</date>
      <address>TARS, Topp Road</address>

      <!-- Use paragraph here  -->
      <p>...</p>

      <!-- 
         This is not a header so lets make it 
         a <div> with a class that represents what it is showing
      -->
      <div class="price">£25 A DAY</div>
   </div>
```

And here's some SASS in case the fiddle doesn't work in future:

```
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;

  background: linear-gradient(90deg, ghostwhite 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 10%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 90%, ghostwhite 100%);
}

.grid-item-workshops {

  background-color: #19252A;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  border-image-width: 100%;
  border: none;

  padding: 0.2em 1em;

  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;

  text-align: left;

  height: auto;

  header {
    margin: 1em auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 2em;


    h1,
    h2 {
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: cyan;
    }
  }

  date,
  address,
  p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

  .price {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

Comment: ive tried but did not work ive edited my initial post with a link to the design i created. This is what i am trying to replicate

Comment: Then you're fundamentally doing the wrong things. Don't use grid - use natural semantic flow and don't use header elements for elements like your offer price on the bottom. I've updated my answer with a j-fiddle.

Comment: @freshcoder - I've updated the j-Fiddle to completely strip it down to the small necessities. It should be a lot easier to follow now: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cnrom41w/4/

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, `margin-bottom` will work just fine. The issue you may be running into here is that *margins are collapsible*. This means that when `<h3>` is directly below `<h2>`, only `<h2>`'s bottom margin is being rendered by the browser. When you remove `<h2>`'s bottom margin, the browser renders `<h3>`'s top margin, so the space between the elements doesn't change. What you have to do is remove `<h3>`'s top margin, then set `<h2>`'s bottom margin to whatever you want.

```css
h2{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h3{
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<h3>STARS, Tartopp Road</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid-gap in your CSS. Something like this:

```
grid-gap: 15px;
```

Comment: ive tried but did not work ive edited my initial post with a link to the design i created. This is what i am trying to replicate

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `margin-bottom: -10px` from your code and add `grid-gap` as per your need.